# Anime about a character in a magic world but with no magic, so he builds guns instead

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching an anime that had a white-haired and red-eyed main character; there's also a blonde loli as a side character. The main character is in a magic world, but knows no spells, so he builds guns: his main two guns are a sniper rifle that is black and red and a pistol which is the same color.

Comment: Was he always in this magic world, or is this an isekai where he got transported there from the real world?

Comment: Sounds a bit like *https://www.novelupdates.com/series/gunota-ga-mahou-sekai-ni-tensei-shitara-gendai-heiki-de-guntai-harem-o-tsukucchaimashita/*, but that's a manga.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

*[Arifureta: From Commonplace to World's Strongest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arifureta:_From_Commonplace_to_World%27s_Strongest)*

> High-schooler Hajime Nagumo is bullied by his classmate for his relationship with the class idol, Kaori. When he and the rest of his class are transported to a fantasy world, all of his classmates get powerful magical abilities, while Hajime only gains the basic alchemical magic to transmute solid materials, a common ability usually found in craftsmen and smiths. During a dungeon raid, he is betrayed by one of his classmates and dropped to the bottom of the dungeon. He survives the fall and creates weapons to escape the dungeon and become stronger. On his journey, he meets with the imprisoned vampire Yue, and later is joined by the bunny-eared Shea, the perverted dragon Tio, and others.

### Anime Opening

Found by searching for `isekai anime "red eyes" "no magic" invents guns` which led to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/fgzfu8/isekai_where_mc_works_effectively/).

Comment: This is what I was going to answer with too.  Technically he has magic, it's just very weak.  And he gains a lot of power even besides the guns.  But it's within spitting distance.